# display data from data base in dropdown not working

Tags: codeigniter

// this is my view part

```
<?php foreach($employees as $employee) : ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $employee->first_name ?>">First name</option>



    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

// employee_id is Salary table Foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the data:

In your controller you call the function in the model and and send the data to the view:

```
$data['employees '] = $this->model_name->get_employees();
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

In the model you execute the sql and send back the data to the controller:

```
  public function get_employees ()
  {
    $this-> db ->select('*');
    $this-> db ->from('employees');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
  }
```

in the view:

```
<select name="select_name"> 
<?php 
foreach($employees as $employee) 
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$employee->first_name .'">'.$employee->first_name .'</option>'; 
} 
?> 
</select>
```

Comment: its not working. i need to show all first_name in a dropdown list. which is belong to employees table. plz help